# How to check if an array key value has an element

Tags: php, arrays, array-key

I have an array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [
        "18.06.2016",
        "18.06.2016",
        "18.06.2016",
        "Test Test",
        "Test Name",
        "Michael Dean",
        "London",
        "1",
        "980.00",
        "",
        "",
        "875.00",
        "875.00",
        "0",
        "64.81",
        "0",
        "810.19"
    ]
    [1] => 
    [
        "18.06.2016",
        "18.06.2016",
        "18.06.2016",
        "Tray 1",
        "Test Name",
        "Adam Richards",
        "London",
        "1",
        "980.00",
        "",
        "",
        "105.00",
        "105.00",
        "0",
        "7.78",
        "0",
        "97.22"
    ]...
```

I want to check if the array key value has 1, after London or not?

Like in the first array key, the value goes like this order:

...,"Test Name","Michael Dean","London","**1**",...

How can I do that?

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: you can use loop and use `[7]` 7th element of array to check

Comment: @Rishi [7] will usually be the 8th element. Or maybe not, as php arrays are more hashmaps. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order is always the same you can just loop through.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($value[4] == 'London' && $value[5] == 1) {
        echo '$array['.$key.'] has London and 1 as key 4 and 5';
    }
}
```

Though you have not appointed keys to the sub-arrays, they still have default keys and you can use these to get to the values you want.

#### Edit

Taking a look at your array I see that there is no logic to the order of the keys. You will not be able to find the values you are looking for unless you assign keys such as `town, id, date, name` to them.

For example:

```
array(
    '0' => array(
        'name' => 'John Doe',
        'town' => 'London',
        'active' => 1,
    )
```

);

Answer (score 0):

Use regular `foreach` loop to check if `London` value is followed by `1`:

```
// $arr is your initial array
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    if ($v[6] == 'London') {
        $hasValue = ($v[7] != 1)? "NOT" : "";
        echo "Item with key $k has 'London' which is $hasValue followed by 1". PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

The exemplary output:

```
Item with key 0 has 'London' which is  followed by 1
Item with key 1 has 'London' which is  followed by 1
...
```